# passing data from a block to another with grand central dispatch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have a top level block where I would like to create a variable and then pass this to a child block.

Do I need to add a retain on the array I'm going to create in the top-level block? Is this thread-safe since I'm creating the data in one and passing it to another?

```
dispatch_async(myCustomQ, ^{

 NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

 // add things to myArray here

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"aMessageToSend"      
        object:myArray];
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't modify `myArray` after the second block is *enqueued* via `dispatch_async()`, then -- yes -- that code is both correct and thread safe.

Note that you are relying on `myCustomQ`'s implied autorelease pool.  I would recommend surrounding that block with an autorelease pool (create one at the beginning, drain it at the end *after* the enqueuing of the main queue block).